# ZeroMQ: socket per data type or just one socket?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, zeromq

I've got a program which receives information from about 10 other (sensor reading) programs (all controlled by myself). I now want to make them communicate using [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/).
For most of the queues the important thing is that the central receiving program always has the latest sensor data, all older messages are not important anymore. If a couple messages get lost I don't care. So for all of them I started out with a separate **`PUB/SUB`** socket; one for each program. But I'm not sure if that is the right way to do it. As far as I understand I have two options:

1. Make a separate socket for every program and read them out in a loop. That way I know by the socket what the information is I'm receiving (I'm often just sending an `int`).
2. Make one socket to which all the programs connect, and with every message I send a `string` which tells the receiving end what the message is about.

All connections are on a **`PUB/SUB`** basis, so creating one socket would well work out. I'm just not sure if that is the most efficient way to do it.

All tips are welcome!

Comment: If you have multiple queues, you can selectively purge one and leave others intact. You can have different options per queue. It's hard to tell if it's important for your task without more detail.

Comment: @9000 - good point. I added this to the question: "For most of the queues the important thing is that the central receiving program always has the latest sensor data, all older messages are not important anymore. If a couple messages get lost I don't care.". Would that mean that I need separate sockets for all of them? Otherwise the one socket maybe gets queued up with data which is already too old by the time it arrives to the central program.

Comment: ^ Fair enough: you can rate-limit the queues separately, and even one queue is overfilled, you can still have fresh data from other queues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> <sub>**-** `PUB/SUB` is fine and allows an easy conversion from N-sensors:1-logger into N-sensors:2+-loggers
> **-** one might also benefit from a conceptual separation of a socket from an access-port, where more than one sockets may get connected</sub>

### How to get always JUST THE ACTUAL ( LAST ) SENSOR READOUT:

If not bound, due to system-integration constraints, to some early ZeroMQ API, there is **a lovely feature exactly for this** via a **`.setsockopt( ZMQ_CONFLATE, True )`** method:

> **`ZMQ_CONFLATE`**: Keep only last message
>   If set, a socket shall keep only one message in its inbound/outbound queue, this message being the last message received/the last message to be sent.
>  Ignores `ZMQ_RCVHWM` and `ZMQ_SNDHWM` options. Does **not** support multi-part messages, in particular, only one part of it is kept in the socket internal queue.

---

### On design dilemma:

Unless your real-time control stability introduces some hard-real-time limit, the **`PUB`**-side freely decides, how often a new value is instructed to `.send()` to **`SUB`**(-s). Here no magic is needed, the less with `ZMQ_CONFLATE` option set on the internal outgoing queue managed.

The **`SUB`**(-s) side receiver(s) will also benefit from the `ZMQ_CONFLATE` option set on the internal incoming queue managed, but given a set of individual `.bind()`-s instantiate separate landing ports for delivery of different individual sensoric readouts, your "last" values will remain consistently the "last"-readouts. If all readouts would go into a common landing pad, your receiving process will get masked-out ( lost ) all readouts but the one that was just accidentally the "last" right before **`.recv()`** took place, which would not help much, would it?

If some I/O-performance related tweaking becomes necessary, the **`.Context( n_IO_threads )`** + **`ZMQ_AFFINITY`**-mapping options may increase and prioritise the resources the **`ioDataPump`** may harness for increased IO-performance

Comment: ZMQ_CONFLATE sounds really quite useful! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're up against a tight real time requirement there's not much point in having more sockets than necessary. ZMQ's fair queuing ought to take care of giving each sensor program equal attention (see Figure 6 in [the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all))

If your sensor programs are on other devices connected by Ethernet, the ultimate performance of your programs is limited by the bandwidth of the Ethernet NIC in your computer. A single thread program handling a single PULL socket stands a good chance of being able to process the data coming in faster than it can transit the NIC.

If that's so, then you may as well stick to a single socket and enjoy the simpler code. It's not very hard dealing with multiple sockets, but it's far easier to deal with one. For example, with one single socket you don't have to tell each sensor program what network port to connect to - it can be a constant.

PUSH/PULL sounds like a more natural pattern for your situation than PUB/SUB, but that won't make much difference.

**Lastness**

Lastness is going to be your (potential) problem. The whole point of things like ZMQ is that they will deliver messages in the order they're sent. Thus you read a message, it is *by definition* the "last" message so far as the recipient is concerned. The recipient has no idea as to whether or not there is another message on the way, in transit.

This is a feature of Actor model architectures (which is what ZMQ is). Messages get buffered up in the transport, and there's no information about the newness of the message to be learned when it's read. All you know is that it was sent some time beforehand. There is no execution rendezvous with the sender.

Now, you either process it as if it is the last message, or you wait for a period of time to see if another one comes along before processing it. The easiest thing to do is to simply process each message as if it is the last.

Contrast this with a *Communicating Sequential Processes* architecture. It's basically the same as an Actor model architecture, except that the transport does not buffer messages. Message sends block until the recipient has called message read.

Thus when you read a message, the recipient knows that it the last one sent by the sender. And the sender knows that the message it has sent has been received at that very instant by the recipient. So the knowledge of lastness is absolute - the message received really is the last one sent.

However, unless you have something fairly heavyweight going on I wouldn't worry about it. You are quite likely to be able to keep up with your sensor data stream even if the messages you're reading aren't the latest in the queue.

You can *nearly* make ZMQ into CSP by setting the high water limit on the sending end's socket to 1. That means that you can buffer up at most 1 message. That's not the same as 0, and unfortunately setting the HWM to 0 means "unlimited size buffer".

Comment: given @kramer65 does not insist on processing each sensor read-outs, I guess the mutually blocking CSP-rendezvous is a thing to be rather avoided. Btw. as you might be aware of, there are python ports of CSP ( PyCSP et al ). And me? Still missing the comfort of `occam` explicit **`PAR`** sections :o) **`TL;DR;`**

Comment: @user3666197 l used Inmos's C on their transputers! Happy but hard days. Take a look at Rust, Mozilla's new language, has CSP built in too. PyCSP sounds interesting, will take a look.

Comment: @user3666197, I suspect that you also think that CSP is just too useful to not exist. Rust looks pretty good, but I wish that someone would do something like ZMQ that did CSP. Unless I've read it all wrong, the reach of Rust's channels would seem to be within a single process, which is a pity because Rust itself looks like a pretty good, quick running language with some attractive features, and sufficiently low level to be a serious contender for the world's next systems language.

Comment: The yardstick to compare against is the unique occam-pi set of **`MOBILE CHAN`** + **`MOBILE PROC`** + **`MOBILE BARRIER`** ... already some 12 years having ZERO attempts to observe any similar conceptual accompanion. **Alan Turing must shiver to watch this from the Computing Heaven** ... ( + Hoare published on CSP already some ~ 62 years ago ... ) Any grant to innovate after half-century? Would jump in on such needed wagon... immediately :o)